# What is the correct statement in order to prevent inserting duplicate value into MYSQL database

Tags: mysql

[image]
I need to avoid duplicate value while inserting value in datagridview into mysql database.. Please any idea

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 1):

The correct statement is

```
create unique index on cash_table (XXX,YYY);
```

You replace the XXX,YYY by the names of the columns whose combination should be unique (perhaps a single column, but then that is a candidate primary key).

Are you trying to be funny by showing the message "Succesfully import" when there is an exception? Not all your users may understand the difference between "Succesfully imported" and "Succesfully import".